# Plugins not working in Eclipse on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

On my brand new Windows 7 machine, I downloaded Eclipse (Galileo) and several Eclipse plugins (Android's ADT plugin, Subclipse, etc.)

After rebooting, neither of these plugins are showing up in the IDE (nothing in the preferences, menus, etc.) but if I click "Installation Details" in the 'About Eclipse' popup, I see all of the plugins listed as Installed Software. (ex. Android DDMS 0.9.5, Subclipse 1.6.5, etc.)

How do I get my plugins to work?

Comment: Do you see anything in the Error Log (Windows > Show View)? Are you using a 32bit or 64bit JVM?

Comment: 32bit, should I be using 64 bit?

and nothing of interest in the error logs...

Answer (score 4):

I installed the following:

- [jre-6u21-windows-x64.exe](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) *{you have to download it using IE-64bit}* (C:\Program Files\Java\jre6)
- [android-sdk_r06-windows.zip](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (C:\Program Files\Java\android-sdk-windows)
- [eclipse-jee-helios-win32-x86_64.zip](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/R/eclipse-jee-helios-win32-x86_64.zip) (C:\Program Files\Eclipse)

First time I tried, I had the same problem as above - no "Android SDK and AVD Manager" in Window menu, and no "Android" item in the Eclipse Window Preferences.

I  [uninstalled the ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#uninstalling) and closed Eclipse. Then launched Eclipse **in Administrator mode**. Then I installed ADT, closed and reopened Eclipse as normal, and it worked :D

Comment: Thanks very much for this - it was very useful.

This is the key - unless you are running it in Administrator mode, the Eclipse installer isn't allowed to write the new plugin files into the Program Files directory. And apparently doesn't notice that it fails to do it, so it thinks it has completed successfully. The plugins aren't really installed unless you've run Eclipse in Administrator mode while installing - that's why they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

After mucking around for a while, I realized that when I copied the Eclipse directories to program files, I put them under the 64 bit directory, not the 32 bit (x86).. after moving eclipse to the new directory and reinstalling the plugin, it seems to work. Not sure if this is correlation or causation so maybe someone with more expertise can shed some light on this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Moved the Eclipse to X86 and worked Thanks man that was getting annoying

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this problem too.  Installing Eclipse 64 bit into C:\Program Files\ and using a 64 bit JVM.  For me the problem turned out to be the UAC (User Access Control).  Once I turned this off via the control panel & restarted, I was able to install my plugins correctly.

No idea why Eclipse or Windows didn't prompt me in some way.  Now to turn it back on after my plugins have installed.

Comment: Turning off UAC works, but is a little extreme - you can work around this by running Eclipse as Administrator while you're installing plugins.

Answer (score 0):

An eclipse under `Program Files` (and not `Program Files (x86)`):

- should be a 64-bit eclipse distro ("`Windows (x86_64)`")
- meant to be used with a 64-bit JDK only.
  Actually, you cannot download the 64-bit eclipse distro without having a warning specifying you need a 64-bit JVM:

> This build requires a 64-bit JVM, and will not run with a 32-bit JVM.
>   You can, for example, use the Sun 64-bit 1.5 JVM for AMD64.
>   Note that the Sun 1.4.2 JVM for AMD64 is 32-bit and therefore cannot be used to run this build.

So: are you sure you have a 64-bit eclipse?
and what `java -version` returns? (Java HotSpot(TM) **64-Bit** Server VM?)

Answer (score 0):

First check the Window -> Preferences -> Android exists or not.

If exists, just point the SDK Location to your android sdk location.

If something missing, just Window -> Android SDK And AVD Manager to download all the sdk you needed.

p.s. Just download the new 64bit jdk from sun, file named jdk-6u17-windows-x64.exe.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\eclipse -> right click -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> Add... -> your username -> Full Control -> Apply

While running Eclipse as administrator does work, I found that doing the above to give yourself and normal Eclipse full write access to the folder is far better since you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it installing Eclipse in an own, user-defined directory, but NOT inside any of those system-managed "C:\Program Files"-directories.