# ADT plugin doesn't work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, adt

I have Eclipse classic version and if I try to add ADT plugin to that it works fine. But when I restart Eclipse the ADT plugin won't be there and I have to install it again and again. Is there any other way in which I can add the ADT plugin permanently?

Comment: Please indicate what version of Eclipse you're using and explain in more detail what you've tried and the results you're seeing. Obviously if it did this for everyone then nobody would use ADT, so there must be something specific about either your configuration or the steps you're taking.

Comment: K, i am sorry about that, I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Indigo Service Release 1, I followed all the steps mentioned in [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) , and then i can go to File> New> Android Project, and create a project. IF i close it or restart Eclipse , File> New> ----. I cannt find a Android Project menu in that.

Comment: Very strange. What OS are you on? Also, Open the About Eclipse dialog and click the Installation Details button. Do you see anything Android-related in the dialog there? Finally, open the Error Log view (Window > Show View...) and use the red X button to clear it out; then install ADT and restart Eclipse. Check the Error Log view after restart to see if there are any errors reported that look related.

Comment: Windows 7, there is nothing related to Android. I tried the error log clear thing before too, even that did not work. It as if I did not install the plugin at all.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to permissions. Windows 7 locks down permissions on the `c:\Program Files` directory, so if you've installed Eclipse there it could be having problems installing new plugins (although I would expect an error rather than the behavior you're seeing after restart). Try installing Eclipse into a non-write-protected directory, or one of the other work-arounds listed here: https://plus.google.com/106300001086744879268/posts/VVdQCbevT2r

Comment: Also, see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978379/plugins-not-working-in-eclipse-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: I tried downloading the ADT zip file, then tried to install the plugin using Archive, it works fine now.
Thanks @Eric

Comment: If an answer helped you, please accept it so everyone gets appropriate credit.